# how to diff push and back use vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

[image]

```
"vue": "^2.6.11"

"vue-router": "^3.2.0"
```

I use Composition API setup function, setup run every times when route push and back, but I just want to do something on push.

How i can diff back and push in page2?

please help.

I try `beforeRouteEnter` and `beforeRouteLeave` but not effect!

`beforeRouteEnter`, `beforeRouteLeave` run every times and I can't got type in router.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Without more code it is hard to tell what's wrong. Can you please update your question so that it shows all your relevant code in a [minimal, complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You might find reading the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

ok i know how to do.
like that

pageA:

```
router.push({
                name: 'pageB',
                params: {
                    init: 'yes',
                },
            });
```

pageB:

```
const params = ctx.root.$route.params;
    if (params && params.init === 'yes') {
        initPage();
    }
```

if you back from pageC->pageB params={}

will be ok.